# how to send float value in url , im sending float value but getting Null values

Tags: c++, arduino, iot

i want to send the values and insert the values into the database, but im getting null values.

```
 float PHValue = Value/10;
  float DOValue= 12.22;
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://itempurl.com/smartpond/AddTemprature?WaterTemperature=""+celsius+""&PHValue=""+PHValue+""&DOValue=""+DOValue+""&currentTime=06-30-2016\"");
```

Comment: Q. What do you get when you add a float and a string? A. A compiler error!

Comment: im not getting compilation error. im getting null values in database becuse its going that variable names instead of going data. problem in double  quotes.i need the api with dynamic parameters

Comment: Use snprintf to print the values into a string (or use stringstream if you want to do it the C++ way).

Answer (score 0):

You can send separately using [print()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) like:

```
int n_decimals = 3;
float PHValue = Value/10;
float DOValue= 12.22;

gprsSerial.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://itempurl.com/smartpond/AddTemprature?WaterTemperature=");
gprsSerial.print(celsius, n_decimals);
gprsSerial.print("&PHValue=");
gprsSerial.print(PHValue, n_decimals);
gprsSerial.print("&DOValue=");
gprsSerial.print(DOValue, n_decimals);
gprsSerial.println("&currentTime=06-30-2016\"");
```

With `n_decimals` the number of decimal places that you want to be printed.

Or as @stark says in the comments you can use `snprintf` to generate your AT command:

```
char command[256];
float PHValue = Value/10;
float DOValue= 12.22;

snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\""
          "http://itempurl.com/smartpond/AddTemprature?"
          "WaterTemperature=%f&PHValue=%f&DOValue=%f"
          "&currentTime=06-30-2016\"", celsius, PHValue, DOValue);
gprsSerial.println(command);
```

Note: I wasn't sure if you want the values in the url to go between quotes, so I left them without.